# Mongoose needs to create objects, but skip the property if another object already has this property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I know the title is confusing but let me explain more clearly.

Here is what my mongoose schema looks like:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  locationKey: {type: String, unique: true},
  wheat: Array,
  barley: Array,
  cty: {type: String, unique: true},
  twp: {type: String, index: { unique: true} , dropDups: true},
  rge: {type: String, unique: true},
});
```

I wrote some code that will create 3500 locations using this schema. The problem is that lots of locations have the same value for `twp`. When this is the case, I need it to still create the object, but not create the `twp` if any other object that has been created has the same `twp`.

As you can see above I tried using the unique approach above. Here is two sample objects for more clarity:

Object One:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f5af9547a341720b0b25cd"),
    "rge" : "034E",
    "twp" : "001N",
    "cty" : "003",
    "locationKey" : "003001N034E",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

If I am going to create a new object, that has `twp: 001N`, I would like it to be created, but to look like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f5af9547a341720b0b25cd"),
    "rge" : "034W",
    "cty" : "004",
    "locationKey" : "003001N034E",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

In server JS I have an array of 3,000 objects, I am looping through this array to create a Location Object for each item like so:

```
locations.forEach(function(item){
  var location = new Location();
  location.locationKey = item.locationKey.trim();
  location.cty = item.cty.trim();
  location.twp = item.twp.trim();
  location.rge = item.rge.trim();
  location.wheat = item.wheat;
  location.barley = item.barley;
  location.save();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add methods pre creating schema, you could do it through `schema.queue` per this [discussion](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/672), here are the test codes under `mongoose v4.4.6`

```
var twpSet = new Set();

LocationSchema.methods.twp1 = function () {
    var curTwp = this.twp;

    if (twpSet.has(curTwp)) {
        this.twp = undefined; // remove the twp field once duplicated
    } else {
        twpSet.add(curTwp); // save the existing twp value
    }
};

LocationSchema.queue('twp1');
```

Test data

```
var l1 = new Loca({
    locationKey: 'k1',
    cty: 'c1',
    twp: 't1',
    rge: 'r1'
});

console.log(l1);
l1.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else 
        console.log('save location1 successfully');
})

var l2 = new Loca({
    locationKey: 'k2',
    cty: 'c2',
    twp: 't1',
    rge: 'r2'
});

console.log(l2);
l2.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else 
        console.log('save location2 successfully');
})
```

Results are

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f5e484a22885dd0362a39a"), "locationKey" : "k1", "cty" : "c1", "twp" : "t1", "rge" : "r1", "barley" : [ ], "wheat" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f5e484a22885dd0362a39b"), "locationKey" : "k2", "cty" : "c2", "rge" : "r2", "barley" : [ ], "wheat" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

---

Another option is to check the existing document before `save` the new document through `.pre('save'` middleware, if find the duplicate `twp`, remove it in the new document, then save it.

```
LocationSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var curTwp = this.twp;
    console.log(curTwp);
    var obj = this;
    Loca.findOne({twp: curTwp}, function(err, loc) {
        if (err)
            next(err);
        else if (loc) {
            // find the duplicate twp before save
            obj.twp = undefined;
            next();
        }else 
            next();
    })

});

var Loca = mongoose.model('Loca', LocationSchema);
```

Test codes

```
var l1 = new Loca({
    locationKey: 'k1',
    cty: 'c1',
    twp: 't1',
    rge: 'r1'
});
var l2 = new Loca({
    locationKey: 'k2',
    cty: 'c2',
    twp: 't1',
    rge: 'r2'
});

console.log(l1);
l1.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        l2.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else 
                console.log('save location2 successfully');
        })  
    }
})
```

Save result as above, to make sure your huge data is saved one by one, you could use [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#synchronous-iteration-functions).

Comment: Ok I added this code to my schema, dropped my database, and rebuilt it. The duplicates are still there. Did I miss something, and/or do I need to call this method when creating a new location? (Using mongoose 4.2.2 which I don't believe is an issue.)

Comment: @fresh5447, I test my codes, it works well. Could you please share your location creation codes to me through gist or something else?

Comment: @fresh5447, I have updated my answer with another option for you. please try it...

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I am trying to implement your suggestion, but I am still getting objects with multiple duplications for the twp section. Do you think it could be because of how I am creating the objects? Updated the code above to show:

Comment: @fresh5447, Obviously, your codes does NOT follow my sample codes, please try this `var location = new Location({locationKey: item.locationKey.trim(),
  cty: item.cty.trim(),
  twp: item.twp.trim(),
  rge: item.rge.trim(),
  wheat: item.wheat,
  barley: item.barley});`

Comment: @fresh5447, you assign the fields of `location` after `new` object. However, in my codes, those fields are assigned in the constructor. Please  read more details from the mongoose issue attached in my answer.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I missed that earlier. I was able to get it to work with your first solution, and modifying the constructor. Thank you!