# How to ignore duplicate properties of other fields in the object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I wrote a for loop that takes a table of data and creates 3,500 objects using this schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  twp: {type: String, index: true, unique: true, dropDups: true},
  rge: {type: String, unique: true},
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
```

Let's say this is the first object created:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f5eb02683e79de61278449"),
    "rge" : "008W",
    "twp" : "004S",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

If any other Objects are instantiated with the value `twp: 004S`, I would like the object to still be created, but have no value for twp. It would look like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f5eb02683e79de61274949"),
    "rge" : "009E",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

As you can see I experimented with adding unique, and dropDups, but this still created multiple objects with the same `twp` value. I also experimented with adding the code below (per someone's recommendation) , but still the same results.

```
var twpSet = new Set();

LocationSchema.methods.twp1 = function () {
    var curTwp = this.twp;

    if (twpSet.has(curTwp)) {
        this.twp = undefined; // remove the twp field once duplicated
    } else {
        twpSet.add(curTwp); // save the existing twp value
    }
};

LocationSchema.queue('twp1');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230055/mongoose-needs-to-create-objects-but-skip-the-property-if-another-object-alread?

Comment: Maybe it is better to update your original question rather than give another same question in SO?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because if you don't include a specific field in a document but that field has a [`"unique"`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-index-and-missing-field) index on it then it is still considered for indexing purposes that the field has a value of `null`.

*Citation:*

> *If a document does not have a value for a field, the index entry for that item will be null in any index that includes it. Thus, in many situations you will want to combine the unique constraint with the sparse option. Sparse indexes skip over any document that is missing the indexed field, rather than storing null for the index entry. Since unique indexes cannot have duplicate values for a field, without the sparse option, MongoDB will reject the second document and all subsequent documents without the indexed field.*

To combat this use the [`"sparse"`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) property on the created index. Heres's a demonstration showing both cases:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


mongoose.set("debug",true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var sparseSchema = new Schema({
  "a": { "type": String, "unique": true, "sparse": true },
  "b": { "type": String, "unique": true }
});

var Sparse = mongoose.model('Sparsetest',sparseSchema);


async.eachSeries(
  [{ "a": 1, "b": 2 },{ "a": 2 },{ "b": 3 },{ "b": 4 },{ "a": 3 }],
  function(item,callback) {
    Sparse.create(item,function(err,doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      callback(err);
    });
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

The code is destined to error, but the output will show you what happens:

```js
Mongoose: sparsetests.ensureIndex({ a: 1 }) { unique: true, sparse: true, background: true }
Mongoose: sparsetests.insert({ a: '1', b: '2', _id: ObjectId("56f706820c2db3902e557cff"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: sparsetests.ensureIndex({ b: 1 }) { unique: true, background: true }
{ _id: 56f706820c2db3902e557cff, b: '2', a: '1', __v: 0 }
Mongoose: sparsetests.insert({ a: '2', _id: ObjectId("56f706820c2db3902e557d00"), __v: 0 })
{ _id: 56f706820c2db3902e557d00, a: '2', __v: 0 }
Mongoose: sparsetests.insert({ b: '3', _id: ObjectId("56f706820c2db3902e557d01"), __v: 0 })
{ _id: 56f706820c2db3902e557d01, b: '3', __v: 0 }
Mongoose: sparsetests.insert({ b: '4', _id: ObjectId("56f706820c2db3902e557d02"), __v: 0 })
{ _id: 56f706820c2db3902e557d02, b: '4', __v: 0 }
Mongoose: sparsetests.insert({ a: '3', _id: ObjectId("56f706820c2db3902e557d03"), __v: 0 })
undefined

                                  ^
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.sparsetests index: b_1 dup key: { : null }
```

So everything is fine for the first four documents created. The first document has unique values for both properties, the second does not duplicate `"a"` and the third and forth do not duplicate `"b"`. Notably here the third and forth documents do not contain an `"a"` property, but since that property is `"sparse"` indexed this is not an issue.

The same is not true though of the `"b"` property, and when we try to insert another document where that property is considered `null` the duplicate key error is thrown for that index. Even though the `"a"` property was still unique the `"b"` already has `null` so it is not.

So where you want a `"unique"` index but you are not going to include the property in **every** document, you must turn on `"sparse"`.

**N.B** The `"dropDups"` option is deprecated and a "no-op" in any release past MongoDB 3.x. It was never a good option to remove existing duplicates from the collection anyway. If you have duplicate data existing then you need a manual process to remove it.

Comment: So in order to implement this, all I have to do is add `sparse: true` to my schema? I tried that but it didn't quite work. Trying to google for more information regarding sparse.

Comment: @fresh5447 Not only is are there hyperlinks to the relevant information ( and a citation ) but there is also a working example showing you what is wrong. So you could not have tried very hard. Read again carefully and look at your code where you are going wrong. The field where you "omit" it from any document needs to have `sparse` if you want that to be `unique`. Otherwise it's a duplicate `null`.